# How to debug python code in OpenERP 6.1

Tags: python, odoo

I am working with OpenERP 6.1 and i am not able to debug the python code
by giving print statements in the python code.

This was quite easy/possible with OpenERP 6.0 where we give the server path
followed by module name and database name to debug the code.

How can i achieve this with OpenERP 6.1??

Please help!!
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What command did you used to use? What result do you get when you try it now?

Comment: This is the command i gave                                       Path to the server$ ./openerp-server.py -u 'modulename' -d 'database name'.                                               After executing this command, i was able to see the result of print statements in that particular module..

Comment: What result do you get when you try it now?

Answer (score 2):

Hi friend you can install ipython. Using ipython you can debug openerp 6.1 at command prompt. kindly make sure that you have installed these packages before hands.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dateutil python-feedparser python-gdata python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-openid python-psycopg2 python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing python-reportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-vatnumber python-vobject python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi
```

I took this list from 
http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/02/22/how-to-install-openerp-6-1-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/

you can also try pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

To debug your Openerp+python code in eclipse, start eclipse in debug perspective and follow the given steps:

1: Stop your openERP running server by pressing "ctr+c".

2: In eclipse go to Menu "Run/Debug Configurations". In configuration window under "Python Run", create new debug configuration(Double click on 'Python Run').

3: After creating new debug configuration follow the given steps:

3.1: In "Main" tab under "Project", select the "server" project or folder (in which Openerp Server resides) from your  workspace.

3.2: Write location of 'openerp-server' under "Main Module".

> Ex: ${workspace_loc:server/openerp-server}.

3.3: In "Arguments" tab under "Program Arguments", click on button "Variables" and new window will appear.

3.4: Then create new "Variable" by clicking on "Edit Variables" button and new window will appear.

3.5: Press on "New" button and give your addons path as value.

> Ex: --addons ../addons,../your_module_path

3.6: Press Ok in all the opened windows and then "Apply".

4: Now into "PyDev Package Explorer" view go to 6.1/server and right click on "openerp-server" file, Select 'Debug As --> Python Run'.

5: Now in "Console" you can see your server has been started.

6: Now open your .py file which you want to debug and set a break-point.

7: Now start your module's form from 'gtk' or 'web-client' and execution will stop when execution will reach to break-point.

8: Now enjoy by debugging  your code by pressing "F5, F6, F7" and you can see value of your variables.

Answer (score 1):

I run the 6.1 server under [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-372/indigosr2) and [PyDev](http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html) without any problems. That lets me add breakpoints and step through the code. Here are the arguments I use:

```
--addons-path ${workspace_loc:openerp-addons-trunk},${workspace_loc:openerp-web-trunk}/addons --config ${workspace_loc:openerp-config/src/server.config}
```

The two breakpoints I find most useful are at either end of the RPC call. On the server side, I put a breakpoint on this line in [`netsvc.dispatch_rpc()`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/6.1/view/4327/openerp/netsvc.py#L344):

```
result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
```

I don't debug the client as often, and not all requests come through the same path, but one useful breakpoint is the first line of [`rpc.tinySocket_gw.execute()`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-client/6.1/view/2101/bin/rpc.py#L123).

Of course, both these breakpoints see a lot of traffic, so I only use them if I'm exploring some feature I'm not familiar with, and I don't know where the code will execute. It can also be useful to put a condition on the breakpoint so it only triggers when a request comes through for a specific model or parameter value.

Here is the config file I use:

```
[options]
debug_mode = False

admin_passwd = ******
db_user = ******
db_password = *******
price_accuracy = 5
smtp_server = **********
ftp_server_port = 8022
ftp_server_passive_ports = 8192:8447
translate_data = False
#log_level = debug_rpc_answer
```

Comment: Thanks Don...But is there a way to debug the python code via Ubuntu command prompt apart from eclipse?? i am having problems with my eclipse installation..It gives error to the lines 'import OSV','import netsvc' etc..

Comment: Maybe you should fix those errors. Perhaps 6.1 requires a package that you don't have installed. One thing I struggled with when I first ran 6.1 was that you have to have the web project included in the addons path.

Comment: I also ran into those import errors in PyDev, @Alchemist777, but I "solved" them by making sure that the project folder is not in the project's Python path.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have:

```
logfile = None
```

in your openerp-server.conf, that gives you the log through the standard output.

Does it helps ?

Answer (score 0):

First: `import logging`

Then :

```
def ExampleFunction(self,cr,uid,ids,context):
        log = logging.getLogger("ExampleClass -- ExampleFunction")
        log.info('test') 
        return True
```

And in your openerp folder `/server/server/openerp-server.log` file
you will see the `log.info` content here ( ExampleClass -- ExampleFunction: test)