# Outputting variables values to OpenERP server log

Tags: odoo

I am doing a lot of enhancements on an existing OpenERP module. I need to be outputting variables(like queries, calculated values, etc) somewhere (maybe the server log or elsewhere) to see what they actually contain. Please how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run the server in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-372/indigosr2) with the [PyDev plugin](http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html). It lets you set breakpoints, step through the code, and examine variable values. You can see more setup details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10092878/4794).

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple print statement in your piece of code in addons and when you start your server you will see the print values on the server log or on terminal. And for advanced debugging of the server values you use python pdb module e.g.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace() #Setting the break point
```

With this you can do debugging in server execution environment.
Thank You